# Python ctypes ERROR: exception: access violation writing 0x00DEF6CC

Tags: python, c, c++, python-2.7, dll

Eu estou tentando importar uma **dll C/C++** com a lib **ctypes** e utilizar uma **função** que a mesma possui internamente, ao passar os parâmetros para esta função me deparo sempre com o erro:

```
ERROR: exception: access violation writing 0x00DEF6CC

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Já utilizei `cast` , `string_buffer` e `POINTER`, porém de todas as formas ainda recebo o mesmo erro

Segue o código:

```py
import ctypes
import sys

file_path = './lib/poc-pagamento-dpos.dll'
integracao_pos = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(file_path)


def main():
    try:
        integracao_pos.carregarRegistros()
        integracao_pos.atribuirCallbacks(callback=display_msg)
        transacao_credito()
    except OSError as e:
        print("ERROR: %s" % e)
        sys.exit(1)


def transacao_credito():
    pNumeroControle = ctypes.create_string_buffer(b"1234567")
    pValorTransacao = ctypes.create_string_buffer(b"15000")
    pNumeroCupom = ctypes.create_string_buffer(b"1234567")
    pTipoOperacao = ctypes.create_string_buffer(b"FA")
    pNumeroParcelas = ctypes.create_string_buffer(b"2")
    pValorParcela = ctypes.create_string_buffer(b"0")
    integracao_pos.transacaoCartaoCreditoDPOS.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_char_p,
                                                          ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_char_p]
    integracao_pos.transacaoCartaoCreditoDPOS(pValorTransacao, pNumeroCupom, pNumeroControle,
                                              pTipoOperacao, pNumeroParcelas, pValorParcela)


def incluir_zeros_esquerda(num, size):
    s = str(num)
    while s < size:
        s = "0{}".format(s)
    return s


def display_msg(msg):
    print("----------------->{}".format(msg))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Alguém tem ideia do que eu possa estar fazendo errado?

Comment: Posta o código C, só com o código python não tem como saber o problema. Também, tente reduzir seu código minimamente pro escopo do problema.

Comment: Talvez postar só o cabeçalho das funções `carregarRegistros`, `atribuirCallbacks` e `transacao_credito` já resolva, mas eu chutaria que o problema está no `atribuirCallbacks`, já que você deveria definir o tipo de argumento que esta função deve receber antes de passar um *callback*.